# What are the relationships among imports, includes, and verification in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I know one Dafny source file can be included in another, leading to textual concatenation of the files prior to verification. But I don't have a clear mental model of the relationships between includes, imports, and which files are verified when. Perhaps an expert can elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least partially documented in the [Dafny Reference Manual](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/blob/master/Docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf) in various sections.

Section 2.0 discusses `include`:

> Included files also obey the Dafny grammar. Dafny parses and processes the transitive closure of the original source files and all the included  files, but **will not invoke the verifier** on these unless they have been listed explicitly on the command line.

(emphasis mine)

Section 3.1 discusses `import`, which is a feature of Dafny's module system. You can only use `import` inside of a module, to make available the definitions in another module. Note that the Dafny module system is independent of how files are stored on disk, unlike some other languages. So if the module you are importing is defined in another file, you may have to include that file if you haven't already.

`import` has no direct influence on whether the imported module is verified or not. Modules in other files will not be verified unless their file is listed on the command line. Modules in the current file are always verified (whether or not they are imported by anyone).